# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - rest connection if specific status code is returned

Tags: spring-boot, connection-pooling

I am using a PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.  However it is holding on to connections when I do not want it to.  Thus my question is this, is there a way to have PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager drop a connection form its queue if a specific httpStatusCode is returned from a client call?

Something like this (preferably) logically

```
if(HttpStatusCode != 200) {
  then drop connection from pool
}
```

or something like:

```
if (HttpStatusCode == 501) {
  then drop connection from pool
}
```

Please note I am using Spring Boot and Rest Template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to use implement a ConnectionReuseStrategy and set it on my HttpClient.